# mysql random selection in inner join

Tags: mysql

Question [Mysql Random Row Query on Inner Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709542/mysql-random-row-query-on-inner-join) is much the same as mine but it was never answered.

I have a master table m and slave s.  S contains 1 to many rows for each m.  I would like a query that selects every master row joined to exactly one randomly chosen slave.

If the table schemas were:

```
M
---
id

S
---
id
mid
```

then, in pseudo code the query would be:
`select * from m inner join s on m.id = s.mid` where `s.id` is one randomly chosen from the values that exist

Can this be translated into real SQL?

Comment: What us your MySQL server version ?

Comment: Is `S.id`, an autoincrement / INT value? Can it be assumed to be uniform without significant gaps (minor lack of equal chance in random selection)?

Comment: [Another bunch of answers](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random)

Comment: Actually, i see my host is running MariaDB.  10.1.31-MariaDB-cll-lve Innodb_version 5.6.36-83.0

Comment: s.id will be autoincrement but there may well be gaps caused by deletions

Comment: @Flixn only for MariaDB version >= 10.3, you can use the second approach in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following query does the required job but using a subquery (not inner join):

```
SELECT *, (SELECT id FROM S WHERE S.mid = M.id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS S_id
FROM M
```

Here is a [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/745a30/1) to test it.
Hope it helps.

Comment: This isn't efficient for a large S table: https://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using [`Row_Number()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) concept. We need to randomly assign row number values within a partition of `mid` in the table `s`. And, do a Join from the `m` table to `s` using `mid` and `row_number = 1`. This will pick a single Random row everytime.

In MySQL version below 8, we can use [User-defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) to emulate `Row_Number()`. To understand how this works, you may check this answer for the explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53465139/2469308

**Note** that this technique will be efficient on Large tables than using a Subquery (in the `SELECT` clause), as it will be doing overall table Sorting **only once**

[**View on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q6Fp96HRBrDgdoc7MA3bd2/0)

```
create table m (id int, m_nm varchar(10));
create table s (id int, 
                mid int references m(mid), 
                s_nm varchar(10));

insert into m values(1, "a");
insert into m values(2, "b");
insert into m values(3, "c");

insert into s values(1, 1, "aa");
insert into s values(2, 1, "aa");
insert into s values(3, 2, "bb");
insert into s values(4, 2, "bbb");
insert into s values(5, 2, "bbbb");
insert into s values(6, 3, "cc");
insert into s values(7, 3, "ccc");
```

---

**Query**

```
SELECT 
  m.*, s_dt.id, s_dt.mid, s_dt.s_nm 
FROM 
  m 
JOIN 
(
SELECT
  @rn := IF(@m = dt.mid, @rn+1, 1) AS row_num,   
  @m := dt.mid AS mid, 
  dt.id, 
  dt.s_nm 
FROM 
( 
SELECT
   id, mid, s_nm, RAND() as rand_num
 FROM s
 ORDER BY mid, rand_num ) AS dt
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0, @m:=0) AS user_vars 
) AS s_dt 
  ON s_dt.mid = m.id AND 
     s_dt.row_num = 1;
```

**Result (Run #1)**

```
| id  | m_nm | id  | mid | s_nm |
| --- | ---- | --- | --- | ---- |
| 1   | a    | 2   | 1   | aa   |
| 2   | b    | 5   | 2   | bbbb |
| 3   | c    | 7   | 3   | ccc  |
```

**Result (Run #2)**

```
| id  | m_nm | id  | mid | s_nm |
| --- | ---- | --- | --- | ---- |
| 1   | a    | 1   | 1   | aa   |
| 2   | b    | 4   | 2   | bbb  |
| 3   | c    | 6   | 3   | cc   |
```

**Result (Run #3)**

```
| id  | m_nm | id  | mid | s_nm |
| --- | ---- | --- | --- | ---- |
| 1   | a    | 1   | 1   | aa   |
| 2   | b    | 3   | 2   | bb   |
| 3   | c    | 7   | 3   | ccc  |
```

---

**MySQL 8.0.2+ / MariaDB 10.3+** solution would be simply the following:

```
SELECT 
  m.*, s_dt.id, s_dt.mid, s_dt.s_nm 
FROM 
  m 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT
    s.*, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER w AS row_num
  FROM s
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY mid 
               ORDER BY RAND())
) AS s_dt 
  ON s_dt.mid = m.id AND 
     s_dt.row_num = 1
```

[**View on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q6Fp96HRBrDgdoc7MA3bd2/1)

Comment: Yeah, I just created my own. Here it is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1624c6/1

Comment: Same result I guess.

Comment: No, all ids are `numeric`. Check the link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1624c6/2

Comment: No worries. Have fun!

Comment: @TeeKea do check the updated answer. There may have been a typo in previous answer; as the concept in the new query still remains the same.

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly.

Comment: @TeeKea I figured out the typo. There was an extra `@` in front of dt1.mid in the previous query.

Comment: Tried you first solution.  Always returns the same results.  Second gives a SQL error.  seems my host is running MariaDB not MySQL

Comment: @Flixn It really does not matter whether MariaDB or MySQL. Second solution will work only if your MariaDB version >= 10.3

Comment: @Flixn regarding the first solution; do you have enough entries in the `S` table ? I doubt that there is not enough sample data. Anyways, looks like you dont have large tables; so you could go with TeeKea's answer, as it is easy to follow, and you most likely dont have performance related constraints.